# What is the conditional probabilities and conditional expectation of $f(X)\vert X$

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, conditional-expectation

There is only one random variable, $X$, and I want to find out the conditional probability and conditional expectation of $f(X)\vert X$.

Here is my thought:

Suppose $X$ is discrete, then $p(f(x)\vert x=x_{0})=\frac{p(f(x),x=x_{0})}{p(x=x_{0})}=
\begin{cases}
  1& \text{ if } f(x)= f(x_{0})\\
  0& \text{ if } f(x)\ne f(x_{0})
\end{cases} $

And the conditional expectation $E(f(x)\vert x=x_{0})=f(x_{0})$

Am I right and what if $X$ is contionuous?

Comment: Same. Will follow immediately once you have learned what $\mathbb E[f(X)|X]$ is.

Comment: @KurtG. Actually I have learnt the definition of $\mathbb E[f(X)|X]$, but I think it's not straightforward to figure it out. Could you give me some tips?

Comment: One of the primary features of this conditional expectation is that anything that is $\sigma(X)$-measurable can be pulled out of $\mathbb E$. Is that the case for $f(X)$?

Comment: @KurtG. Yes, and I think it is a simple and stupid question, but it is confuing when I try to deal with it by the definition of conditional expectation.

Comment: Finding the answer yourself with a few terse hints is anything but stupid. Better than reading all the details from somebody else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually we have some basic properties of $E\{g(X)\vert Y=y \}$:

$E\{g_1(X)+g_2(X)\vert Y=y \}=E\{g_1(X)\vert Y=y \}+E\{g_2(X)\vert Y=y \}$

$E\{g_1(X)*g_2(Y)\vert Y=y \}=g_2(y)E\{g_1(X)\vert Y=y \}$